# adding SSD drive to HDD with OS

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, partitioning, ssd

I have an older laptop that needs some performance help. I currently have a 500 gb drive with Win 7 and Recoery Partition. The computer has a COA. I'm looking to purchase a smaller SSD drive, probably 64 or 128 GB to use as my boot drive. I'm wondering what would be the best way to go about something like that. Should I just disconnet the HDD and only leave SSD plugged in and install it? Is there a way for me to somehow point to SSD to do the recovery? I'm not sure what the best thing would be to do for this kind of process. I still want to keep the 500 gb drive for my storage needs.

Or should I just get a SSHD? laptop: Thinkpad T430

Comment: Does your laptop contain places to connect two HDDs simultaneously?

Comment: @music2myear - its a thiknpad t430 so yes

Comment: Whenever I've migrated from HDD to SSD I've always used it as a good excuse to do a fresh install. It's helped by the fact that you already have a backup - in the form of your existing files on the original HDD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your factory restore will most likely only restore to a drive of equal or larger size than the original (the OEM restore process is an image expansion, so if the image is of a 500 GB drive, then you'll need at least 500 GB for it to work).  If you have a Windows install disc from the same generation as the CoA sticker, then you can do a fresh install to the new/smaller SSD with the code on the sticker.  But note that this WILL NOT move over your preferences/settings/etc from the old HDD without additional effort.

All that said, have you considered a hybrid drive (I some manufactures are calling them HSSD or SSHD).  These have a decently sized flash array smashed to a large spinning disk drive.  Built in firmware determines the sectors with the most consistent IO demand and moves them into the flash portion (faster IO) and keeps lower request requirements on spinning disk where cheap is good enough.  You get more size, you get more speed, and you don't have to classify what needs to be on the SSD vs HDD by hand.  Thats a lot of winning.

With the hybrid design, the migration is also as simple as "clone existing drive to new drive; expand partition(s) as necessary."  So things will 'just work' when you start with the new drive.  And the cloning can be done with a myriad of freely available tools (including some that probably come in the box with the new drive, or probably a download link these days, who needs more CDs).

Comment: As examples of hybrid disk drives:  WD Blue SSHD https://www.wdc.com/products/internal-storage/wd-blue-sshd.html  or Seagate's FireCuda line: http://www.seagate.com/consumer/upgrade/laptop-solid-state-hybrid-drive/

Answer (score 1):

If possible just buy something bigger SSD, not just 64gb or 128gb. If you are a power user, just buy something big. However, if you are just an ordinary user (browse internet and use office apps most of the time). 256gb should suffice.

Also take in to consideration that SSD's max write cycles is directly proportional to its size so the bigger the size, the better.

In regards to the HDD, you can use it for files storage (separated from the os), if your laptop offers extra space for another hard drive, if not just use a bigger sized (storage) SSD

Comment: No I'll be installing SQL Server Mgmt Studio and .NET for starters. I would but they just get really expensive. What do you think about SSHD? with 16 GB cache?

Comment: If that's what you can afford. It can be suffice. Another thing, it could do if most of fhe frequent apps (referring as a collection) you are using is under 16gb, including/excluding system files.

Comment: I'm just trying to be realistic. A 500gb SSD will run me probably close to 250-300$ - while a good 1tb - 16gb probably half the price.

Comment: Then go with the SSHD. Please accept my answer if you find it helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I'm waiting to hear more answers - also the part obout OS is unanswered.

Comment: No problem. You should really do so :)

Answer (score 1):

I did a similar thing on my MacBook Pro (used an OWC Data Doubler to take out the optical drive and install the 256 GB SSD, keeping the 500GB HD internally as a data disk). Not sure if that would work for you and your laptop, but so far for me its been perfect. I don't know if I qualify as a "power user" but I do graphic design work from home and run the Creative Suite every day on the SSD, and 256GB has been plenty so far.

Comment: Yes I'm able to swap the optical drive with a 2nd HDD. Thanks.